# MySQL conflict port number with non existing application

Tags: mysql, laragon

currently my computer conflicts with MySQL and default port number is 3306. I also have tried to change the port number to 3307 and failed.

And based on the picture, the current MySQL application is pointing to non existing application which i already deleted.

For Services running on my Window 10, there is no "MySQL". I also include netstat -a

Is there anyways that able to reset back the MySQL in Window 10? Or how do i resolve this conflicts.

[image: Laragon error]

[image: netstat -a | find "LISTENING"]

Comment: Did you tried looking for services on port  "3306"  ? Do a global search on a my.cnf, i don't run windows, but change is there is a my.ini or my.cnf file. In there certain paths can be set.

Comment: my guess is that something else goes wrong upon startup, and that the process is not shutdown correctly and when you try to start again you find the port occupied. And you change and so on... Take a look at running processes. Check error logs. Confirm network status. Shared resources (network). Disks health. User credentials. `Try to find out why port is occupied. Changing port is wrong way to solve this. Understand the error and fix it instead.`